# Adding data from csv file to database using django

Tags: python, django, csv

I have Django model as follows:

```
class TraxioRelations(models.Model):
    corgemeente = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    coradres = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    corhuisnr = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
```

That model creates a table in the database with `id` as follows:
[image]

Now I want to add records from csv file to that model. The csv file is as follows:

[image]

I use `copy` command as follows:

```
COPY master_traxiorelations(corgemeente, coradres, corhuisnr)
FROM '/path/to/file.csv' CSV HEADER delimiter ';' encoding 'ISO-8859-1';
```

And when I execute it, I get an error as follows:

```
[2017-08-21 15:50:49] [22P04] ERROR: extra data after last expected column
```

But when I add an `id` to `copy` command, thus `COPY master_traxiorelations(id, corgemeente, coradres, corhuisnr)`

And to `csv` file also:

[image]

Then it works fine.

How can I add the data from file to the database, without adding id to copy command and to csv file?

Comment: I would recommend using an external library for this purpose called django import export.Docs link is as follows: https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io

Answer (score 0):

I solved it adding `id` to the model as follows:

```
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

Adding `id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)` enables auto incrementation of the id. Thus my model looks like :

```
 class TraxioRelations(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    corgemeente = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    coradres = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    corhuisnr = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
```

And then `copy` command works without adding id column in the csv file.

```
COPY master_traxiorelations(corgemeente, coradres, corhuisnr)
FROM '/path/to/file.csv' CSV HEADER delimiter ';' encoding 'ISO-8859-1';
```

Hope that this helps if someone else has the same problem.